# How to debug stream().map(...) with lambda expressions?

Tags: java, debugging, lambda, java-8

In our project we are migrating to java 8 and we are testing the new features of it.

On my project I'm using Guava predicates and functions to filter and transform some collections using `Collections2.transform` and `Collections2.filter`.

On this migration I need to change for example guava code to java 8 changes. So, the changes I'm doing are the kind of:

```
List<Integer> naturals = Lists.newArrayList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);

Function <Integer, Integer> duplicate = new Function<Integer, Integer>(){
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer n)
    {
        return n * 2;
    }
};

Collection result = Collections2.transform(naturals, duplicate);
```

To...

```
List<Integer> result2 = naturals.stream()
    .map(n -> n * 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using guava I was very confortable debugging the code since I could debug each transformation process but my concern is how to debug for example `.map(n -> n*2)`.

Using the debugger I can see some code like:

```
@Hidden
@DontInline
/** Interpretively invoke this form on the given arguments. */
Object interpretWithArguments(Object... argumentValues) throws Throwable {
    if (TRACE_INTERPRETER)
        return interpretWithArgumentsTracing(argumentValues);
    checkInvocationCounter();
    assert(arityCheck(argumentValues));
    Object[] values = Arrays.copyOf(argumentValues, names.length);
    for (int i = argumentValues.length; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = interpretName(names[i], values);
    }
    return (result < 0) ? null : values[result];
}
```

But it isn't as straighforward as Guava to debug the code, actually I couldn't find the `n * 2` transformation.

Is there a way to see this transformation or a way to easy debug this code?

**EDIT: I've added answer from different comments and posted answers**

Thanks to `Holger` comment that answered my question, the approach of having lambda block allowed me to see the transformation process and debug what happened inside lambda body:

```
.map(
    n -> {
        Integer nr = n * 2;
        return nr;
    }
)
```

Thanks to `Stuart Marks` the approach of having method references also allowed me to debug the transformation process:

```
static int timesTwo(int n) {
    Integer result = n * 2;
    return result;
}
...
List<Integer> result2 = naturals.stream()
    .map(Java8Test::timesTwo)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
...
```

Thanks to `Marlon Bernardes` answer I noticed that my Eclipse doesn't show what it should and the usage of peek() helped to display results.

Comment: You don’t need to declare your temporary `result` variable as `Integer`. A simple `int` should do as well if you are `map`ping an `int` to an `int`…

Comment: Also i add that there is the improved debugger in IntelliJ IDEA 14.

Now we can debug the Lamdas.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I usually have no problem debugging lambda expressions while using Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA. Just set a breakpoint and be sure not to inspect the whole lambda expression (inspect only the lambda body).

[image: Debugging Lambdas]

Another approach is to use `peek` to inspect the elements of the stream:

```
List<Integer> naturals = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
naturals.stream()
    .map(n -> n * 2)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**UPDATE:**

I think you're getting confused because `map` is an `intermediate operation` - in other words: it is a lazy operation which will be executed only after a `terminal operation` was executed. So when you call `stream.map(n -> n * 2)` the lambda body isn't being executed at the moment. You need to set a breakpoint and inspect it after a terminal operation was called (`collect`, in this case).

Check [Stream Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) for further explanations.

**UPDATE 2:**

Quoting [Holger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) comment:

> What makes it tricky here is that the call to map and the lambda
>   expression are in one line so a line breakpoint will stop on two
>   completely unrelated actions.
>
> Inserting a line break right after `map(`
>   would allow you to set a break point for the lambda expression only.
>   And it’s not unusual that debuggers don’t show intermediate values of
>   a `return` statement. Changing the lambda to `n -> { int result=n * 2; return result; }`
>   would allow you to inspect result. Again, insert line
>   breaks appropriately when stepping line by line…

Comment: Thanks for the print screen. What version of Eclipse do you have or what did you do to get that dialog? I tried using `inspect` and `display`  and get `n cannot be resolved to a variable`. Btw, peek is useful too but is prints all the values at once. I want to see each iteration process to check the transformation. Is it posible?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler SR2 (with Java 8 support installed from Eclipse's marketplace).

Comment: Are you using Eclipse too? Just set a breakpoint on `.map` line and press F8 multiple times.

Comment: I'm using same Eclipse as you. I've put a breakpoint on `.map` but can only see `n` value can't see the transformation `n*2`. On guava I can debug the `apply` method and see argument value and transformation block and debug the behaviour

Comment: @Fede: what makes it tricky here is that the call to `map` and the lambda expression are in one line so a line breakpoint will stop on two completely unrelated actions. Inserting a line break right after `map(` would allow you to set a break point for the lambda expression only. And it’s not unusual that debuggers don’t show intermediate values of a `return` statement. Changing the lambda to `n -> { int result=n * 2; return result; }` would allow you to inspect `result`. Again, insert line breaks appropriately when stepping line by line…

Comment: @Holger great contribution. Do you mind if I include your comment on my answer so others can read it easily?

Comment: As a side note: Eclipse Lunar, with full Java 8 support was released last week.

Comment: @Holger your comment was instrumental for debug. I could do what I wanted by using `{ int result=n * 2; return result; }` in multiple lines. Also using method reference as Stuart pointed worked for the same purpose

Comment: @MarlonBernardes don't know why I couldn't debug and see what you posted so I think it could be something on my Eclipse. But I could use as workaround Holger's suggestion and worked beautifuly. Also the method reference approach posted by stuart. I'd upvoted multiple times if I could.

Comment: @Fede I don't know either. Maybe you could try upgrading to Eclipse Lunar and see if it works. Anyway, I'm glad Holger's suggestion worked for you (I quoted him on my updated answer) Cheers!

Comment: @Marlon Bernardes: sure, you may add it to the answer as that’s the purpose of comments: helping to improve the content. Btw., I have edited the quoted text adding code formatting…

Comment: @MarlonBernardes I changed and accepted you answer since you put Holger's comment and technically that solved my question. Thanks for that

Comment: In Eclipse (Mars) this works fine for `.map(n->Math.cos(n))`, but it doesn't work at all for `.map(Math::cos)`.  (It stops on "map", but not on the various evaluations of the expression, like you can with the "manual" lambda.)  Similarly I also cannot set a breakpoint for each step of `.peek(System.out::println)`

Answer (score 42):

IntelliJ has such a nice plugin for this case as a **Java Stream Debugger** plugin. You should check it out:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9696-java-stream-debugger?platform=hootsuite

It extends the IDEA Debugger tool window by adding the Trace Current Stream Chain button, which becomes active when debugger stops inside of a chain of Stream API calls.

It has nice interface for working with separate streams operations and gives you opportunity to follow some values that u should debug.

[image: Java Stream Debugger]

You can launch it manually from the Debug window by clicking here:

[image]

Comment: Too bad this is not valid for optionals, which can grow up to the same complexity

Comment: I am using Intellij 2023 and this plugin has been merged within Intellij by default already, you can find it when Debugger is started at the end of the Debugger tab

Answer (score 25):

Debugging lambdas also works well with NetBeans. I'm using NetBeans 8 and JDK 8u5.

If you set a breakpoint on a line where there's a lambda, you actually will hit once when the pipeline is set up, and then once for each stream element. Using your example, the first time you hit the breakpoint will be the `map()` call that's setting up the stream pipeline:

[image: first breakpoint]

You can see the call stack and the local variables and parameter values for `main` as you'd expect. If you continue stepping, the "same" breakpoint is hit again, except this time it's within the call to the lambda:

[image]

Note that this time the call stack is deep within the streams machinery, and the local variables are the locals of the lambda itself, not the enclosing `main` method. (I've changed the values in the `naturals` list to make this clear.)

As [Marlon Bernardes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542150/1441122) pointed out (+1), you can use `peek` to inspect values as they go by in the pipeline. Be careful though if you're using this from a parallel stream. The values can be printed in an unpredictable order across different threads. If you're storing values in a debugging data structure from `peek`, that data structure will of course have to be thread-safe.

Finally, if you're doing a lot of debugging of lambdas (especially multi-line statement lambdas), it might be preferable to extract the lambda into a named method and then refer to it using a method reference. For example,

```
static int timesTwo(int n) {
    return n * 2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> naturals = Arrays.asList(3247,92837,123);
    List<Integer> result =
        naturals.stream()
            .map(DebugLambda::timesTwo)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

This might make it easier to see what's going on while you're debugging. In addition, extracting methods this way makes it easier to unit test. If your lambda is so complicated that you need to be single-stepping through it, you probably want to have a bunch of unit tests for it anyway.

Comment: My problem was that I couldn't debug the lambda body but your approach of using method references helped me a lot with what I wanted. You could update your answer using Holger approach that also worked perfectly by adding `{ int result=n * 2; return result; }` in different lines and I could accept the answer since both answer were helpful. +1 of course.

Comment: @Fede Looks like the other answer got updated already, so no need to update mine. I hate multi-line lambdas anyway. :-)

Comment: Yes, had to changed it since technically the question asked for lambda expressions and method references aren't lambda... although could serve for the same purpose. I'd be glad to accept your answer if you post Holger's comment. It would be fair since Holger's answered and yours helped too.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: I prefer single line lambdas too. So usually I remove the line breaks after debugging ⟨which applies to other (ordinary) compound statements as well⟩.

Comment: @Fede No worries. It's your prerogative as the asker to accept whichever answer you prefer. Thanks for the +1.

Comment: I think that creating method references, besides making methods easier to unit tests also makes for a more readable code. Great answer! (+1)

Answer (score 11):

Just to provide more updated details (Oct 2019), IntelliJ has added a pretty nice integration to debug this type of code that is extremely useful.

When we stop at a line that contains a lambda if we press <kbd>F7</kbd> (step into) then IntelliJ will highlight what will be the snippet to debug. We can switch what chunk to debug with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and once we decided it then we click <kbd>F7</kbd> again.

Here some screenshots to illustrate:

1- Press <kbd>F7</kbd> (step into) key, will display the highlights (or selection mode)
[image]

2- Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times to select the snippet to debug
[image]

3- Press <kbd>F7</kbd> (step into) key to step into 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Intellij IDEA 15 seems to make it even easier, it allows to stop in a part of the line where lambda is, see the first feature: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/06/intellij-idea-15-eap-is-open/

Answer (score 1):

Debugging using IDE's are always-helpful, but the ideal way of debugging through each elements in a stream is to use peek() before a terminal method operation since Java Steams are lazily evaluated, so unless a terminal method is invoked, the respective stream will not be evaluated.

```
List<Integer> numFromZeroToTen = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

    numFromZeroToTen.stream()
        .map(n -> n * 2)
        .peek(n -> System.out.println(n))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```