# Putting conditional breakpoints in lambda expressions in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

How can I put a conditional breakpoint in a lambda expression in IntelliJ. For eg. I have a statement `stream().map(s -> s * 2).forEach(...)`. I want to put a conditional breakpoint `s == 5` on this statement.

IntelliJ doesn't recognize `s` as valid. Why is that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24541786/2711488

Answer (score 1):

This is not part of IntelliJ 14, but it will be part of IntelliJ 15.

You can see it is part of the [features being added](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/06/intellij-idea-15-eap-is-open/) and you can probably download the [EAP Build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+15+EAP) and check if it already has this feature implemented.

Than being said, in IntelliJ 14 you can still stop in a lambda if you change it (momentarily for debugging purposes) to a block of code.

```
stream().map(s -> { return s * 2; }).forEach(x -> {System.out.println(x); });
```

IntelliJ does let me put a break point within the lambda block. It will still complain/suggest that this can be simplified to a lambda without the block of code, but you can leave it like this momentarily while you debug it and change it to a simpler expression once you're sure everything works.