# How to debug lambda expression in Java 8 using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, lambda, java-8

I am trying to debug a simple Java application which is using Lambda Expression. I am not able to debug Lambda Expression using normal Eclipse debugger.

Comment: Line breaks and step-by-step debugging is based on line numbers. So you may have to insert line breaks into the lambda expression to be able to separate it from its surrounding context. Besides that, it works without problems, even with Eclipse versions not knowing about lambda expressions (it’s all about matching line numbers with source code text).

Comment: IMHO, if it needs to be debugged, it should not be a lambda but a private method...

Comment: Also consider `peek(System.out::println)` in your stream.

Comment: Convert back to anonymous inner class.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta: sometimes, you want to set a break point to find out whether and when it’s evaluated and/or inspect the parameters provided by the caller. That’s independent of the lambda’s complexity.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24542150/2711488

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's late answer but hope it is useful for someone.
I use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542150/10605477 but sometimes when code is a bit messy or I can't get data I just break the code and insert peek.

```
protected Optional<Name> get(String username) {
    return profileDao.getProfiles()             
            .stream()
            .filter(profile -> 
                    profile.getUserName().equals(username))
            .peek(data -> System.out.println(data))
            .findFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the expressions into statements.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

// expression
boolean allMatch1 = list.stream().allMatch(s -> s.contains("Hello"));
// statement
boolean allMatch2 = list.stream().allMatch(s -> {
  return s.contains("Hello");
});
```

You can now set the break-point on the `return s.contains("Hello");` line

Comment: There is no need to transform the expression to a statement. Just inserting a line break after `->` is sufficient.