# How to read in all Files in a sub-directory using Files.walk exactly once?

Tags: java, file-io, java-8, java-stream

I am attempting to read in all of the files in all subdirectories of a directory. I have the logic written, but I am doing something slightly wrong because it is reading in each file twice.

To test my implementation, I created a directory with three subdirectories in it each having 10 documents in them. That should be 30 documents in total.

Here is my code for testing that I am reading in the documents correctly:

```
String basePath = "src/test/resources/20NG";
Driver driver = new Driver();
List<Document> documents = driver.readInCorpus(basePath);
assertEquals(3 * 10, documents.size());
```

Where `Driver#readInCorpus` has the following code:

```
public List<Document> readInCorpus(String directory)
{
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(directory)))
    {
        return paths
                .filter(Files::isDirectory)
                .map(this::readAllDocumentsInDirectory)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

private List<Document> readAllDocumentsInDirectory(Path path)
{
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(path))
    {
        return paths
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(this::readInDocumentFromFile)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

private Document readInDocumentFromFile(Path path)
{
    String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
    String outputClass = path.getParent().getFileName().toString();
    List<String> words = EmailProcessor.readEmail(path);
    return new Document(fileName, outputClass, words);
}
```

When I run the test case, I see that the `assertEquals` failed because there were 60 documents retrieved, not 30, which is incorrect. When I debugged, the documents were all inserted into the list once, and then inserted again in the exact same order.

Where in my code am I reading in the documents twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is in `Files.walk(path)` method. You're using it incorrectly. So it traverses your file system like a tree.
For example you have 3 folders - `/parent` and 2 children `/parent/first`, `/parent/second`. 
`Files.walk("/parent")` will give you tree `Paths` for each folder - parent and 2 children, and actually this happens in your `readInCorpus` method.

And then for each `Path` you're calling second method `readAllDocumentsInDirectory` and same story here it's traversing folders like a tree.

For `readAllDocumentsInDirectory` with `/parent` path it will return all documents from both children folders `/parent/first` and `/parent/second` and then you have 2 more calls of `readAllDocumentsInDirectory` for `/parent/first`, `/parent/second` that return documents from both folders.

Thats why you have your documents doubled. To fix it you should only call method `readAllDocumentsInDirectory` with `Paths.get(basePath)` argument and remove `readInCorpus` method.

Comment: Interesting. That fixed the problem. It makes sense when you explain it, but I didn't understand that `Paths.walk` would automatically include files in the subdirectories. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this comes from a misunderstanding of how `Paths` and `Files.walk` work. In `Driver#readInCorpus`, you have the following stream operation:

```
return paths
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .map(this::readInDocumentFromFile)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your mapping function (`this::readInDocumentFromFile`) reads all of the documents from every directory in each path in the `Paths.walk` stream, which includes the top level directory *and* the subdirectories.

This means that all of the files that are below the starting directory in the path are read once, and then re-read when going through the subdirectories.

This isn't entirely clear from looking at the streams, but you should take a look at [How to debug stream().map(...) with lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24541786/4816518) to see how to better debug streams and avoid this problem in the future.

That means that you can skip the intermediate step of calling `Driver#readAllDocumentsInDirectory` and just have this in `Driver#readInCorpus`:

```
public List<Document> readInCorpus(String directory)
{
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(directory)))
    {
        return paths
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(this::readInDocumentFromFile)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```